# Save info from a form in a Bootstrap modal into a PHP session

Tags: php, html, session, modal-dialog

I'm trying to use the modal component from Bootstrap to get some info from it and save them into a session.

I want people to put their first name, last name and email adress into that form and when they click on submit, these info are saved into the session so I can use them on an other page. Also, when they click on the button, they are sent on Paypal's website and after paying, they are sent back on my website  where I should display their info. Problem is : I can't get the infos.

This is the first time I use the Session function in PHP and I managed to save a variable and use it from a page to another. Also, I successfully stored a data from a form and used it. But when I put that form into the modal, I have an error on the website.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Entrez vos informations</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <form name="identifiants" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                        <p>Nom :
                            <input type="text" name="nom" size="20" required /></p>
                        <p>Prénom :
                            <input type="text" name="prenom" size="20" required /></p>
                        <p>Adresse email :
                            <input type="email" name="email" size="20" required /></p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="WNNJPMXAANNPY">

                        <input class="btn btn-outline-warning" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit!" />


                        <?php if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
                        $_SESSION['nom'] = $_POST['nom'];
                        $_SESSION['prenom'] = $_POST['prenom'];
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
                    }
                    ?>


                    </form>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the code of my other page :

```
   echo $_SESSION['logiciel'];
   echo $_SESSION['nom'];
   echo $_SESSION['prenom'];
   echo $_SESSION['email'];
   ?>
```

I did put a session_start(); at the beggining of all my pages, it still doesn't work.
I tried to put the php part of the first page out the form, out of the div and out of the modal but nothing works. Yet, I still display the 'logiciel' variable on the other page because I save it earlier in the code.

Comment: You should add `session_start()` at the very top of your page and also check if it posted any data right after that.

Answer (score 0):

It's the best to use a db for these cases but to answer your question, you need to add a code `session_start()` on top of your file before you call a session variable.

Example

File1:
Set session name and its value

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['firstname'] = 'Your Firstname';
?>
```

File2:
print the session variable value that was set before

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['firstname'];
?>
```

To check all sessions just use `var_dump($_SESSION)`

Comment: I did add the session_start() at the beggining of all my pages, it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you check and try `var_dump(isset($_POST['Submit'])); exit;` maybe its not proceeding to setting value in a session.

Comment: Thing is, I don't want to set the value of the Session myself, I wanted it to be set from the form in the modal. The session works perfectly until I try to get the data from the modal

Comment: Where should I paste that? `var_dump(isset($_POST['Submit'])); exit;` I tried at the end of  `<?php if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
                        $_SESSION['nom'] = $_POST['nom'];
                        $_SESSION['prenom'] = $_POST['prenom'];
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
                    }
                    ?>` 
It didn't show me anything

Comment: put that code before `if(isset($_POST['Submit']))` it should display true or false.

Comment: It displays false at first but when I submit it changes to true. So it does set the value in the session right?